# 1D CNN and Moving Average for Time Series. Any formal relationship?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, moving-average

Intuitively, a 1D CNN (for a good filter) is very similar to a weighted moving average of a time series.

Are there any formal (mathematical) relationships between the two?

Can it be shown that under certain circumstances a 1D CNN would learn an exponentially-weighted moving average?